# unable to set default option in select dropdown with dynamically fromed dropdown ng-model in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my Angularjs application, I need to return select drop down with its selected option dynamically. So I have used the following function:

```
 function getCellRendererMapping(data) {

     if (data.order == 6) {
         return function(params) {
             params.$scope.payRateRegDataOptions = data.data;
             var dynamicScopename = "data.' + params.colDef.field + data.order +'"
             $scope.dynamicScopename = data.data[0];
             // console.log("dynamic scope value" +  $scope[dynamicScopename]);
             return '<select ng-options="eachPayRate.text for eachPayRate in payRateRegDataOptions" name="payrate_s' + params.column.index + '" id="payrate_s' + params.column.index + '" ng-model="dynamicScopename"></select>';
         }
     }

 }
```

So what happening is that the dropdown is correctly forming and is populating nicely with the dropdown options too. But the problem I am facing is the default set option in the dropdown is not working out, even though I have used the following code to set the default option, my ng-model, (`dynamicScopename`) is not getting set.

```
   $scope.dynamicScopename = data.data[0];
```

Comment: What is the value of dynamicScopename  and also what is being populated in the select??. Remember that select shows default value only when the ngModel value matches with the one of the populated values in the dropdown

Comment: how you want use this? why not just use some directive for this?

Comment: The value of dynamicScopename should be the first one of the dropdown options. In my dropdown the options are getting populated correctly and I am just assigning at index '0' to dynamicScopename. $scope.dynamicScopename = data.data[0];

Comment: Grundy, I use this to form ag-grid cell renderer in grid options as  cellRenderer:getCellRendererMapping(inputs). (http://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-grid/index.php). Is there any sample reference code for the directive you are mentioning because even there I need to form that name of the selected model of the dropdown dynamically. Please let me know if I did not follow you correctly.

Comment: i think you should add that use some custom grid

Comment: also, do you know that value for `var dynamicScopename = "data.' + params.colDef.field + data.order +'"` not used everywhere?

Comment: yes it is not used  anywhere else. Just to ensure, I changed it to var dynamicScopename = "dataXYZ.' + params.colDef.field + data.order +'", but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add `ng-selected="dynamicScopename"` hope it helps.

```
return '<select ng-options="eachPayRate.text for eachPayRate in payRateRegDataOptions" name="payrate_s' + params.column.index + '" id="payrate_s' + params.column.index + '" ng-model="dynamicScopename" ng-selected="dynamicScopename"></select>'
```